# How to remove padding from vector icons in Expo io

Tags: react-native, expo

If i use the vector icons in Expo i see lot of padding space is added around the icon by default. [Green color in the screenshot attached, thats the padding for a 15px icon]. Is there a way to remove that extra padding? Tried manual overriding of padding and margin but didn't worked. 
Sample code for the screenshot provided:

```
<Entypo name="triangle-down" size={15} color="#9013FE" style={{
                                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                                    }}/>
```

Doc reference code from here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/guides/icons.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try having negative margin such as below:
`style={{ marginEnd: -10 }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a surrounding view with width and height smaller than the icon size and style overflow: "hidden"